# .htaccess http_referer filter works on chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, safari

I'm having trouble with allowing visitors from a specific http referer to view one page on a wordpress site. Right now in the htaccess file it only allows linkedin referers to arrive on the `certain-page` and this works on Chrome but it is not working on Firefox or Safari and follows the redirect rule immediately. Does Firefox have it's own syntax? Why is it ignoring it? Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.linkedin\.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?certain-page$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?certain-page/$
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```